# Showing hierarchy in sql query (self-relationship table)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a self-relationship table in my database.  I'm trying to make a query that shows my rows like this:

```
Father 1
SonofFather1
Sonoffather1
Father 2
SonofFather2
Sonoffather2
SonofFather2
Sonoffather2
Father 3
.
.
.
```

What i have is this:

```
WITH parents AS
    (SELECT parent.* FROM SubjectBase as parent WHERE parent.ParentSubject IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT son.* FROM SubjectBase as son WHERE son.ParentSubject IS NOT NULL)
    SELECT * from parents;
```

But it returns the parents first, and then the sons.
How can i show the parent followed by its sons?

Comment: It gave me this error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Did you put the clause outside the CTE?

Comment: I've tested it with the clause outside the CTE, but it says that parent and son are invalid column names